# AngularJS Bootstrap Calendar - Mwl - connecting e.g with Outlook

Tags: angularjs, outlook, calendar

I use this calendar in my AngularJS 1.5.8 application:

[AngularJS Bootstrap Calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink)

My question now is maybe a little bit strange but I need a connection of this calendar with the Outlook calendar in that way that the events in my AngularJS Bootstrap calendar should be synchronized with outlook (so that the events are also shown in outlook) and maybe also in the other direction. 
Have someone done anything in that direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downvoted your question, because it looks like you haven't tried anything at all. 
This community aims to help you when you run in to errors and difficulties during development. We are not here to do the work for you.

I do understand that while you are developing you might run into issues, when you do, try and provide us with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is short for **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample.

*That being said*:
You should check out [the outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations), they will tell you how to retrieve and post events. Once you have your data, you should transform it into models your calendarComponent understands. Once this is done, you should simply be able to render all events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did a google research but I could not found something helpful. Sorry if I expulsed against the rules! Your hint was really helpful!